# Removing Tuck Tape from an unfinished window frame

Tags: painting, windows, vapor-barrier

The builder taped the vapour barrier to the window frames in my basement.  Is this normal?  I attempted to peal it off but the glue residue is stuck to the wood.

Any suggestions on how I can remove it?  Is it possible to prime over the tape?

[image: tried to remove tuck tape]
[image: tuck tape everywhere]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your builder is an idiot. That is just plain lazy.  Yep, Goo Gone, or maybe some mineral spirits. As a last resort if the aforementioned don't work, try acetone.  Acetone dissolves most glues, but also can damage the finish. Test a small area first.

Comment: Are we looking at the sub-framing of the window that simply wasn't faced/cased over when the window was installed, or was the builder actually stupid enough to tuck-tape the barrier to the window casing?

Comment: Yes, that is the window casing.  the builder hired some lazy workers who cut a lot of corners.

Comment: One of those things that makes you want to go Berserker with a battle axe. I'd recommend gentle use of a heat gun to help the adhesive let go, but that finish underneath might not like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using some Goof Off for removing the residue.