# How do I remove 20 year old sun damaged tuck tape from PVC siding?

Tags: cleaning, vinyl, vinyl-siding

This question is similar, but deals with intact tape:  [Removing Tuck Tape from an unfinished window frame](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/removing-tuck-tape-from-an-unfinished-window-frame)

In my case, it has been out in the sun for some time on PVC siding window trim.  One side was in shade and I could get the tape off, then Goo Gone worked well to take off the stuck adhesive.

On the other side the tape is brittle and has little strength.  So far the largest piece I've gotten off is about 1 cm2.  Goo gone doesn't seem to go through the tape.  Ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Try WD-40. It has always worked for me.

Comment: Have you actually used this on tape with an intact surface film?

Comment: Yes, and so have others. WD-40 is famous for this ability. Perhaps it may not work on some materials, but why not try it if it does not harm PVC?

Comment: Sorry I had to downvote.   You can't have someone try something that may or may not work and call that an answer.   Maybe a poorly devised comment but not answer.

Comment: I can't see that this answer is any worse than "I've had good luck with acetone".

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with acetone for dissolving adhesives and old tape. Try a small hidden spot to make sure it doesn't damage the pvc.

Comment: PVC is soluble in acetone.  Not instantly, but it softens and changes the finish.

Comment: Yes it is. You have to use it carefully, drop some on and wipe it off quickly... and do this many times. The finish has probably been altered from the sun.